# How to run a PowerShell script at logon for all (current and future) users with elevated permissions without UAC

Tags: windows-10, script, scheduled-tasks, uac, windows-task-scheduler

I'm building a login script for our company.  Some of the things it will do include installing printers, mapping drives, setting wallpapers, etc. Many of these things will require elevated permissions. Many of these things will also require the username (IE cannot be run as system, must have user context to check groups, etc).

I first looked at Intune/MEM (we are 100% M365/Azure, no on-prem servers).  You can go to AzureAD > Devices > Scripts and apply a script, but my understanding is that this only runs once and then again if it is changed, not at every login as desired.

Second I tried `shell:common startup`.  I quickly realized this would result in a UAC prompt at every login (making registry changes, etc).  No go.

Then I tried a scheduled task.  This works well as you can run it as the user with "highest privileges" toggle.  The problem I ran into here is that you have to create the task under each user.  I really need this to apply to all users *as well as* future users. IE, if a new user logs into a conference room PC I need it to run the script immediately.

So, that's where I stand. What are my options? Is there a way to create a system wide scheduled task that runs at login of every user under the user context?  Am I missing something with Microsoft Endpoint Management that constitutes a *proper* login script? Group Policy?  I think the `startup` folder is completely out, but open to options here too (do not want to disable UAC though).

Comment: Perhaps you could use the event trigger *AtStartup* rather than *AtLogOn*. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=windowsserver2019-ps for examples.

Comment: I don't think this will work as I need to know WHO is logged in so I can query AD groups, etc.

Comment: @THEJOATMON You should write up an answer with your details and screen shots for the options that worked for you here. I've done this before what you clarified in the comments of the answer provided, but I think this warrants a self-answer in the name of helping others to see what you did in case that's what they need. Tag me back if you add it in and I'll +1.

Comment: Good idea. I have posted my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

There exist software products that allow running specific commands
in elevated/administrator mode.

Example products (more may exist):

- [Steel Run As](http://www.steelsonic.com/steelrunas.htm)
  (commercial)
  Uses the administrator account while hiding the administrator
  password that is required for making it work.
- [NirSoft AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/run-as-different-user.html)
  (free)
  A more elaborate RunAs program.

Another solution might be to use the Task Scheduler to schedule
running a script  as administrator, but with a trigger that is
never activated, and to run it with the command :

```
schtasks /run /tn "task-name"
```

For more information see the article
[Windows 7: Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt - Create](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html).

Comment: Okay putting a shortcut to `schtasks /run` in your startup is a brilliant workaround to the UAC. However, I don't think it solves the requirement of running the task AS the user that is logging in.  `When running the task, use the following user account` seems to be the sticking point.

Comment: And now that I think about it, in the linked article, why not just use the scheduled task trigger for logon? Not really relevant to my issue, just curious.

Comment: Yes, but you have said that some actions need to be done under the user's login. If that's not the case, the scheduled task can do anything. But if you need the user-name, the task can get that only if the task is run under that user account, which means that it's not running in admin mode, so then you need my answer for executing some commands as admin from a script that is not admin.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Let's reset a bit. I like your `schtasks /run` idea, but when creating the task what would I put for `when running the task, use the following user account`?  If I put `SYSTEM` and use the run command, it outputs the computer name for `$env:UserName` instead of the username.  And I assume if I put any specific user, it will alwasy run as that. IE I don't think it matters who runs the run command.

Comment: Resetting. You need a task run at login. If it's for all users, then it must be user-agnostic with admin permissions. If all you need is the currently-logged user-name, then this PowerShell command should get it: `Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | select username`.

Comment: `Get-WmiObject` is not valid.  I tried `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name` and `whoami` which both returned `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.  `$env.Username` is the computername.

Comment: `(Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem).Username` returns the expected username!  So I should be able to set the scheduled task to "run as" SYSTEM then use the `schtasks /run` command from a batch file in `shell:common startup`.

Comment: Yes, `Get-WmiObject` still works for me although it was superseded by `Get-CimInstance`. That's computers for you.

Comment: Nope. Access denied. It only works if it I run it as an administrator. Which puts me right back at square one.

Comment: There are only two options: (1) Run everything as admin, get logged-user, do everything as admin, or (2) Run everything as user, but execute specific commands in elevated mode. You have to decide which one.

Comment: After a lot of testing and clearing up some confusion on my part, scheduling a task FROM an elevated user to run as SYSTEM will run when ANY user logs in WITH elevated permissions AND I can still get the logged in user using `(Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem).Username`.  No need for a script in the startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic solution, based on @harrymc's answer: (Formatted for readability)

```
schtasks.exe /Create 
  /SC ONLOGON 
  /RL HIGHEST 
  /ru "BUILTIN\Users" 
  /TN "companyname\Login Script" 
  /TR "'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe' 
      -windowstyle hidden 
      -noninteractive 
      -ExecutionPolicy Bypass 
      -File C:\companyname\scripts\ls.launch.ps1" 
  /F
```

Here is the full solution I implemented, if anyone is interested.  So far it seems to be working well. We use Azure policies for most things, but it is nice to have this running on every computer in case we need it.

> `ls.install.bat`
>
> Installs powershell, copies necessary scripts and installs the scheduled task
>
> ```
> @echo off
> IF NOT EXIST c:\companyname mkdir c:\companyname
> IF NOT EXIST c:\companyname\scripts mkdir c:\companyname\scripts
> IF NOT EXIST c:\companyname\logs mkdir c:\companyname\logs
> IF NOT EXIST p:\!scripts\ net use p: \\10.1.0.20\public /user:asdf asdf
> IF EXIST p:\!scripts\ echo Drive already mapped
> if NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" (
>     echo Installing PowerShell 7...
>     start /wait msiexec.exe /i "p:\installs\PowerShell-7.1.3-win-x64.msi" /QN /L "c:\pwshinstall.log"
>     echo Done.
> ) else (
> echo Powershell already installed
> )
> echo Copying files...
> xcopy "p:\!scripts\companynameLoginScript\ls.launch.ps1" "c:\companyname\scripts" /Y
> echo Done. Installing task...
> schtasks.exe /Create /SC ONLOGON /RL HIGHEST /ru "BUILTIN\Users" /TN "companyname\Login Script" /TR "'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe' -windowstyle hidden -noninteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\companyname\scripts\ls.launch.ps1" /F
> ```
>
> `ls.launch.ps1`
>
> This is what actually runs on startup. It downloads an updated script and executes it because it was hard to have a script update itself.
>
> ```
> <#  
> Script: Loginscript Launcher
> Purpose: This script simply downloads the loginscript and executes
> Updated: 2021-10-08
> #>
>
> #----------------------------------------------#
> #---- ENVIRONMENT/TOOLS SETUP -----------------#
> #----------------------------------------------#
>
> #$env:SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS = 1 #this is to avoid security warning prompts when launching tools like baretail
>
> $param1=$args[0]
> if ($param1 -eq "-d" -or $param1 -eq "-D") {
>     $isDev = $true
> }
>
> #todo: Move to config file
> $logpath = "c:\companyname\logs\loginscript"
> $scriptpath = "c:\companyname\scripts\"
> $scripturl = "http://servername/ls.core.ps1"
> $logfile = "$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss").log"
>
>
> #----------------------------------------------#
> #---- FUNCTIONS -------------------------------#
> #----------------------------------------------#
>
> Function log($message) {
>     Write-Output "[$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss")] $message" | Out-file "$($logpath)\$($logfile)" -append
>     if ($isDev) { Write-Host "[$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss")] $message" }
> }
>
> Function createFolder($path) {
>     if (-!(Test-Path $path)) { New-Item -Type Directory -Path $path }
> }
>
> function updateScripts() {
>     try {
>         Invoke-WebRequest -uri $scripturl -OutFile "$($scriptpath)\ls.core.ps1"
>     } catch {
>         $statuscode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
>         Write-Host "StatusCode:" $statuscode
>         if (Test-Path "$($scriptpath)\ls.core.ps1") {
>             log "ERROR: ($statuscode) COULD NOT UPDATE. Using local script."
>         } else {
>             log "ERROR: Unable to update script and no local script found. Exiting."
>             exit
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> #----------------------------------------------#
> #---- MAIN CODE BLOCK -------------------------#
> #----------------------------------------------#
>
> if ($isDev) {
>     log "Running in development mode..."
> }
>
> createFolder $logpath
> createFolder $scriptpath
>
> #update scripts
> updateScripts
> #execute core loginscript
> & "$($scriptpath)\ls.core.ps1"
> ```

> `ls.core.ps1`
>
> The *real* login script. Currently it just sets company wallpaper and changes a setting in Microsoft Teams. It also logs to a standard location so it's easy to check for issues. Eventually it will log to a log aggregation system.
>
> ```
> <#
> Script: ls.core
> Purpose: core Login script for companyname
> #>
>
> #----------------------------------------------#
> #---- ENVIRONMENT/TOOLS SETUP -----------------#
> #----------------------------------------------#
>
> $user = (Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem).Username
> $wpfilename = "companyname_Wallpaper.jpg"
> $wppath =  "c:\companyname\$wpfilename"
> $wpurl = "http://downloads.companyname.com/$wpfilename"
> $appdata = [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::ApplicationData)
>
> #----------------------------------------------#
> #---- FUNCTIONS -------------------------------#
> #----------------------------------------------#
>
> function isAdministrator
> {
>     $user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
>     (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
> }
>
> Function log($message) {
>     Write-Output "[$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss")] $message" | Out-file "$($logpath)\$($logfile)" -append
>     if ($isDev) { Write-Host "[$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss")] $message" }
> }
>
> function downloadFile($source, $destination) {
>     try {
>         Invoke-WebRequest -uri $source -OutFile $destination
>     } catch {
>         $statuscode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
>         log "ERROR: Could not download $source ($statuscode)"
>     }
> }
> function setLockScreenImage() {
>     #TODO: Check if lockscreen already set
>     try {
>         log "Setting Lock Screen ($wppath)"
>         REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP /f
>         REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP /v LockScreenImagePath /t REG_SZ /d $wppath /f
>         REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP /v LockScreenImageUrl /t REG_SZ /d $wppath /f
>         REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP /v LockScreenImageStatus /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
>     } catch {
>         $statuscode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
>         log "ERROR: Could not apply registry changes ($statuscode)"
>     }
> }
>
> function setWallpaperImage() {
>     #TODO: Check if wallpaper already set
>     try {
>         log "Setting Wallpaper ($wppath)"
>         reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d $wppath /f
>         rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True
>     } catch {
>         $statuscode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
>         log "ERROR: Could not apply registry changes ($statuscode)"
>     }
> }
>
> function updateTeams() {
>     $configFile = "$appdata\Microsoft\Teams\desktop-config.json"
>     if (Test-Path -Path $configFile) {
>
>         #get current value
>         $teamsConfig = (Get-Content $configFile -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
>         $isOpenAsHidden = $teamsConfig.appPreferenceSettings.psobject.properties.Where({$_.name -eq "openAsHidden"}).value
>
>         #only update the file if it's not already set
>         if (!$isOpenAsHidden) {
>             log "Updating $configFile"
>             Stop-Process -name "Teams"
>             try {
>                 $currSettings = Get-Content $configFile
>                 $currSettings.replace('"openAsHidden":false', '"openAsHidden":true') | Set-Content $configFile
>             } catch {
>                 $statuscode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
>                 if (!$statuscode) { $statuscode = "UNKNOWN CODE"}
>                 log "ERROR: Could not update Teams settings ($statuscode)"
>             }
>             & $appdata\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe"
>         } else {
>             log "Teams already set to start hidden"
>         }
>     } else {
>         log "ERROR: Teams config file not found ($configFile)"
>     }
> }
>
> #----------------------------------------------#
> #---- MAIN CODE BLOCK -------------------------#
> #----------------------------------------------#
>
> log "$user has logged in"
>
> if(-!(Test-Path $wppath)) {
>     downloadFile $wpurl $wppath
> }
> if(Test-Path $wppath) {
>     setLockScreenImage
>     SetWallpaperImage
> }
>
> updateTeams
>
> log "Login script complete"
> ```